# Spring-amqp-QueueBuilder should hold ref to Queue and not String name

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have 2 anonymous queues. They both are setup with `___Declarables extends AbstractAmqpDeclarables`
which are instantiated as @Bean on startup.

But at the time of startup - rabbitMQ hasnt given the queues a name, so one of the 2 queues gets 2 bindings and the other queue gets no binding. If `QueueBuilder` held a reference to queueObject and not name this object creation might be delayed enough to have rabbitMQ generate the name.

This is for a rabbitMQ generated name on the format `amq.gen-<random>`
and not spring-amqp generated name on the format `spring.gen-<random>`

Edit: if I call `QueueBuilder.durable();` instead of `QueueBuilder.durable(queueName);` the generated name becomes `spring.gen-<random>` instead of `amq.gen-<random>`

Minimal reproducible example:

1. Producer

```
@Bean("amqpEmitterEventPublisherAdapter")
public EventPublisher<OurChangeEvent, Boolean> emitterEventsPublisherAdapter(
@Qualifier("amqpTemplate") RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate
) {
final var publisher = new OurAmqpProducerImpl(rabbitTemplate);
return new OurEventAmqpPublisherAdapter(
    publisher,
    amqpConfigProps.getGlobalExchangeName(),
    ourEventsConfigProps.getOurEventsBindingPrefix(),
    ourEventsConfigProps.getOurEmitEventsBindingDataSuffix(),
    amqpConfigProps.isEnabled()
);
}
```

2. Producer - with different suffix - a new binding

```
@Bean("amqpEmitterEventPublisherAdapter2")
public EventPublisher<OurChangeEvent, Boolean> emitterEventsPublisherAdapter2(
@Qualifier("amqpTemplate") RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate
) {
final var publisher = new OurAmqpProducerImpl(rabbitTemplate);
return new OurEventAmqpPublisherAdapter(
    publisher,
    amqpConfigProps.getGlobalExchangeName(),
    ourEventsConfigProps.getOurEventsBindingPrefix(),
    ourEventsConfigProps.getOurDifferentSuffix(),
    amqpConfigProps.isEnabled()
);
}
```

1. Declarables - this is the problem. Name of queue is "". Ok with 1 declarable. Not with 2 declarables.

```
    @Bean("emitEventsDeclarables")
    public Declarables emitEventsDeclarables(
        @Qualifier("mainAmqpAdmin") RabbitAdmin admin,
        @Qualifier("GlobalAmqpExchange") Exchange exchange
    ) {
        final var bindingKey =
            ourEventsConfigProps.getOurEventsBindingPrefix() +
                ".*." +
                ourEventsConfigProps.getOurEmitEventsBindingDataSuffix();
        final var cfg = new OurEventsExclusiveDeclarables(
            exchange,
            ourEventsConfigProps.getOurEmitEventsQueueName(), //=""
            bindingKey,
            true
        );

        final var declarables = cfg.declarables();
        for (Declarable d : declarables.getDeclarables()) {
            d.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin);
        }
        return declarables;
    }
```

2. Declarable has queue Name also ""

```
@Bean("emitEventsDeclarables2")
public Declarables emitEventsDeclarables2(
@Qualifier("mainAmqpAdmin") RabbitAdmin admin,
@Qualifier("GlobalAmqpExchange") Exchange exchange
) {
final var bindingKey =
    ourEventsConfigProps.getOurEventsBindingPrefix() +
        ".*." +
        ourEventsConfigProps.getOurDifferentSuffix();
final var cfg = new OurDifferentExclusiveDeclarables(
    exchange,
    ourEventsConfigProps.getOurEmitEventsQueueName(), //=""
    bindingKey,
    true
);

final var declarables = cfg.declarables();
for (Declarable d : declarables.getDeclarables()) {
    d.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin);
}
return declarables;
}
```

Hence we got 2 declarables with anonymous queue name. Now the Spring-amqp-QueryBuilder gets confused. One of the 2 anonymous queues gets both bindings, and the other queue gets no binding.

```
public class OurEventsExclusiveDeclarables extends AbstractAmqpDeclarables {
    private final boolean isSingleActiveConsumer;

    public OurEventsExclusiveDeclarables(
        Exchange exchange,
        String queueName,
        String bindingKey,
        boolean isSingleActiveConsumer
    ) {
        this.exchange = exchange;
        this.queueName = queueName;
        this.bindingKey = bindingKey;
        this.isSingleActiveConsumer = isSingleActiveConsumer;
    }

    /** Exclusive queue with no name.
     * @return Declarables
     */
    @Override
    protected Declarables declarables() {
        QueueBuilder queueBuilder = 
 //Here is the problem - QueryBuilder is built too soon. RabbitMQ has not had time to generate a name
QueueBuilder.durable(queueName).exclusive();
//This will result in a spring generated name - not a RabbitMQ generated name
//QueueBuilder.durable().exclusive();
        System.out.println("binding queue name:" + queueName+ " to exchange:" + exchange.getName() + " with binding key:" + bindingKey);
        if (isSingleActiveConsumer) {
            queueBuilder.singleActiveConsumer();
        }
        final Queue queue = queueBuilder.build();
        final Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(bindingKey).noargs();
        return new Declarables(queue, binding);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - it's not clear what you mean with just a textual description.

Comment: Ive added an example. Not including all objects, but enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: It would be more useful to have a complete project so I can just run it locally rather than having to copy/paste; I'll take a look but, in general, it's preferred to have spring name anonymous queues rather than having to wait for the broker to name them.

Comment: I think the problem is here: `return new DestinationConfigurer(queue.getName(), DestinationType.QUEUE);`. It does take the current `name` from a queue for `Binding`. And even if we block waiting for the actual queue name, it doesn't mean that we change it when we call `channel.queueBind()`

Comment: Reason for using rabbitMQ generated names and not spring-named( InRabbitMQ documentation): "exclusive queues should be server-named...When auto-delete or exclusive queues use well-known (static) names, in case of client disconnection and immediate reconnection there will be a natural race condition between RabbitMQ nodes that will delete such queues and recovering clients that will try to re-declare them. This can result in client-side connection recovery failure or exceptions, and create unnecessary confusion or affect application availability." https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#properties

Comment: @ArtemBilan Either we have to block-wait, or change the queue name to set the binding to the correct queue. Or it means spring.amqp doesnt support more than one server-named queue.

Comment: Where in spring.amqp is the queue name - updated to get the server-named - rabbitmq named - queue? For anonymous queues - bindings should not be set until that point in the code.

Comment: Yeah - looks like the `BindingBuilder.DestinationConfigurer` needs to keep a reference to the `Queue` object rather than extracting the name during the build process. 

Please open an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah - looks like the `BindingBuilder.DestinationConfigurer` needs to keep a reference to the `Queue` object rather than extracting the name during the build process.

Please open an issue on GitHub.

Fix will be in the next release, in the meantime, this is a work around:

```java
@Bean
Binding b1(Queue q1, DirectExchange ex) {
    return new Binding(q1.getName(), DestinationType.QUEUE, "ex", "foo", Collections.emptyMap()) {

        @Override
        public String getDestination() {
            return q1.getActualName();
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Added bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/2438